# What is the difference between "./somescript.sh" and ". ./somescript.sh"

Tags: linux, shell

Today I was following some instructions to install a software in Linux. There was a script that needs to be run first. It sets some environment variables.

The instruction told me to execute `. ./setup.sh`, but I made a mistake by executing `./setup.sh`. So the env was not set. Finally I noticed this and proceeded.

I want to know the difference between these two methods of invoking a script. I am completely new to Linux so please be as elaborate as possible.

Comment: FYI -- the folks writing those instructions probably should have asked you to write `source ./setup.sh` rather than `. ./setup.sh` to make it less ambiguous; the mistake you made is a very common one.

Comment: @Charles Duffy Thanks for pointing this out. Yes the instructions are for internal use, so I guess they are intended for gurus.

Comment: `source` is Bash only, whereas `.` is portable to Bourne shell.  If the instructions are not Bash-specific, you cannot use `source` even though it would be more readable.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`./setup.sh` runs the script, a new shell will be started that runs the script. That new shell cannot affect the parent shell that started the script.

`. ./setup.sh` is a shorthand for `source ./setup.sh` and it will run the script in the current shell, instead of starting a new shell to run it. This means the script can alter the behavior of the current shell, e.g. set new environment variables.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: I just realized I didn't answer the other part of your question .. but the answer by leeroy does that. I kind of answered something else, but I hope it helps :-)

The `sh` function runs bash on the script you present it with. See [the man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sh) for more info, but you can see `sh` is basically the synonym for `bash`

When you run a script ala `./setup.sh` it identifies the script based on what is at the top of the file, normally referred to as the ["Shebang"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))

A bash script would have

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Or similar at the top of the file, allowing you to use the dot method. You can also use other things, like a Python script can have

```
#!/usr/bin/env/python
```

And if your path is correct, it would run the script as a Python script instead of a bash one using the dot notation.

Hope that explains it in a simple manner!

Comment: That's all true, but it does not answer the question. The key point is  that `. ./setup.sh` can alter the current shell, and `./setup.sh` cannot.

Answer (score 0):

`.` refers to the current directory.  So `./script.sh` means run the script in the current directory.

`../script.sh` would run script.sh in the parent directory.

`. ./script.sh` (with a space between the dots) would complain in some shells like csh but in bash `. foo` is shorthand for `source foo`.

Comment: Just figured that out.  I tried it in csh and it said "command not found".  I see now that in bash it's a shortcut for "source".

Answer (score 0):

Just run "`source /path/to/setup.sh`"

This will set up environment variables in current shell.